# JFrog Artifactory Repo - Unusual Data Transfer

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory

We have configured Azure Devops YAML pipeline and integrate with JFrog Artifactory. While running the pipeline for one stage there is a large amount of downloads occurring and we noticed that some unusual data transfer is happening.

For each environment there are about 15 stages, for every stage the it will download Artifactory from JFrog, we have triggered 2 environments that is like 30 stages altogether. Normally we expect 30 downloads from JFrog, but it was 80+ that is like 3* more.

How can we minimise the downloads in Artifactory?

Comment: The question is not clear and does not contain enough information. It is not clear what is being downloaded from Artifactory. You are writing that it downloads Artifactory from JFrog on every stage? is it downloading Artifactory or downloading packages from Artifactory?
In general you should focus on the pipeline you created. This is what causing the downloads.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, Could you share the download artifact task setting and JFrog download history here? This should be an issue with your pipeline task settings.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?